# Can we assume a function to be a polynomial in olympiads ??

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, problem-solving, functional-equations

While solving Olympiad level functional equation questions, I have often found that assuming the functional equation to be a polynomial makes it easier to solve and in $99\%$ of the cases the function given in the solution is a simple polynomial.

So is it fine to assume the function to be a polynomial and proceed ??

Comment: +1 to your question, which is an interpretation question.  Surprised that anyone would downvote such a relevant question.  The strategy that you are referring to, is part of the strategy that I refer to as *meta-cheating*, which also includes assuming that a problem would not be assigned unless it was solvable, based on the theory that was recently taught.  In my experience is a very powerful weapon in Math classes up to and including all undergraduate Math classes.  I have no experience with Math graduate school.  ...see next comment

Comment: If you try to *meta-cheat* in an Olympiad, two things will happen: [1] First, the judges will spend a few moments laughing at your attempt.  [2] Then, your answer will be (at least partially) downgraded.  What you are doing is equivalent to a $4$ year old child attempting to lie to a homicide detective or a child psychologist.  There isn't any artifice that you can try that the Olympiad judges haven't seen over and over again.

Comment: @user2661923 What if we find solutions when the function is a polynomial and prove that there is no function satisfying the given relation if the function is not a polynomial ?

Comment: Assuming that you *prove* that you have found **all** polynomial solutions, then you are **not** meta-cheating, and the judges will have nothing to laugh at.

Comment: Note: It is very hard to prove that there is no non-polynomial function that could satisfy a given functional equation.

Comment: @CalvinLin if the function's domain as well as range  is the set of integers, then ig it is easy to prove

Comment: It will be hard if $f:Q\to Q$ or $f:R\to R$..

Comment: @AnAlien Can you give an example of what you're thinking about?

Comment: @CalvinLin Take [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4300167/975208) as an example. In this question , I have found the functions which are polynomials and satisfy the given relation. Now we can say that if the function is not a polynomial i.e. if the power is a fraction or negative, the output won't be a whole number for every input (whole number)...

Comment: No, that's a misconception. Why must it look like $f(x) = \sum a_i x^{b_i}$? Why couldn't it be (say) $f(odd) = 1, f(even) = 0 $ which isn't in "polynomial-ish" form? Your solution is still worth $0^+$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks..I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they ask you to find all functions, then no. You may say that if their proposed solution only involves polynomials, then you are fine, but you actually didn't prove that your solution is complete.